# What gurantees the existence of generalized eigenvectors of rank m?

Tags: generalized-eigenvector

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A with multiplicity $m>1$. Then there could be two cases:

1. There are $m$ linearly independent eigenvectors of A corresponding to $\lambda$.In this case, the geometric multiplicity is the same as the algebraic multiplicity.
2. The geometric multiplicity is less than algebraic multiplicity.

This information is quite useful while solving a system of linear ODEs. If we have the situation in case 2, we resort to finding generalized eigenvectors.

For example, suppose A is a $3\times 3$ matrix with repeated eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ and we found only a single eigenvector $v_1$ by solving $(A-\lambda I)v_1 = 0$. A nontrivial solution is always guaranteed for a homogeneous case $Bx = 0$, where $B$ is singular.

Now, we find the generalized eigenvalue of rank 2 by solving the equation
$$(A-\lambda I)v_2 = v_1$$.

See that $(A-\lambda I)$ is singular and it's a non-homogeneous case. Why is it so that the system is not inconsistent? In fact $$(A - \lambda I)^mv = 0$$ for a nonzero $v$ makes it possible to repeat the process of finding generalized eigenvectors up to $m-1$ steps. What makes $(A - \lambda I)^mv = 0$ possible.

Can anyone clear it in simple language? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at a matrix in Jordan form, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form   It should then be quite clear what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, @YuvalPeres. I will check.

Comment: I like reversing the order. For a Jordan block of size $k$  and eigenvalue $\lambda,$   begin with a vector $v$   with $(A-\lambda I)^k  v = 0$   but  $(A-\lambda I)^{k-1}  v \neq  0.$  Then the basis vectors for that block are $v, (A-\lambda I)  v,  \ldots (A-\lambda I)^{k-1}  v.$  The final one is a genuine eigenvector. This way of doing it, with all integer eigenvalues, is doable by hand.  All together, we gate an integer matrix $P,$   so that the only occurrence of fractions occurs in a single number  as $P^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det P}   P',$   where $P'$  is the adjoint matrix,  all integers.

Comment: Thanks @willJagy